# Duda respecto a números primos en Python

Tags: python, condiciones, while, input, else

Espero se encuentren bien. Tengo una duda a la hora de comprobar si un número es primo o no en Python , no entiendo por que se pondría el "2" específicamente. Entiendo que el "%" significa el residuo, pero: ¿si el residuo es 2 es primo? no entiendo. Agradecería la ayuda y paciencia para poder resolver esa duda. Muchas gracias y feliz noche.

Escribir un programa que pida al usuario un número entero y muestre por pantalla si es un número primo o no (método bucle).

```
n = int(input("Introduce un número entero positivo mayor que 2: "))
i = 2
while n % i != 0:  
    i = i + 1  
if i == n:
    print(f"{n} es primo")
else:
   print(f"{n} no es primo")
```

Comment: El programa no está comparando si el residuo es `2`, el programa tiene `n % i != 0` donde `i = 2` al inicio. Es decir, divide `n` entre `2` y compara si el residuo de esa división es diferente de `0`, por ejemplo `3 / 2` el residuo sería `1` y es diferente de `0`.

Answer (score 1):

`i` vendría a hacer el divisor, y vale 2 para que no haya un error.

Si valdría 1 el resultado siempre va a decir que es número primo porqué cualquier número dividido entre 1 no tiene residuo.

Lo que busca el bucle es encontrar el divisor más próximo a `n` y después en base a ese divisor que encontró un `if` compara que si `i` (divisor) es igual a `n`, dado el caso que esto sea así es un número primo porqué no encontró otro divisor que no sea si mismo, caso contrario no es primo y se ejecuta el `else`.